# How a kernel is ported on hardware?

Tags: kernel, task-scheduler

In smp schedulers, a scheduling daemon is run on every core, actually i want to know how this is possible that (NBR_CORES) copy of a program run separately on different cores? (I'm new in kernel and system software, correct me if i make mistake). thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is called Affinity. A program can be made to run on only one (certain) core. It can be set in the task manager or you can use a front end that set it in task manager for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank, but i think you did get my meaning wrong, maybe because of my bad clarification. For best clarification of my mention, please take a look at this address: http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch04lev1sec2, here in schedule() part is mentioned that: "... The schedule() function is run independently by each processor. Consequently, each CPU makes its own decisions on what process to run next.", i actually mean how this happen that every core has its own version of schedule() function?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean anymore. When a computer boots, only one cpu is running and only on one core. Then when the os scheduler starts the cpu communicate with the other cores and cpus as the OS say it should and teach the other process units how to interpret the process table. Then all cores fork processes in time slots according to priority setting. Did I answer what you wanted to know - and more?

Comment: Yeah, somehow. thanks a lot. but i think there should be an arrangement module in kernel to say every core must have its own copy of schedule() function. i look for such a module. Do you think the same? maybe this module runs at first on (as you mentioned) core 0 and do the leader ship from there. Am i right?

Comment: It is one way of doing it, but it could also be made so that one core do all the scheduling and only communicate what long jump should be done every time timer interrupt kicks in. This is probably the most efficient way of doing it on multi processor environment with eight way qpi interconnection.

Comment: so, how can we understand which method is used for doing so?